# Annulus of convergence of $e^{z+1/z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on the following problem:

> Determine the Laurent series $f(z)=e^{z+1/z}$ and find its annulus of convergence about the origin.

**What I've done so far:** Using $e^w=\sum_0^\infty w^n/n!$ I can find that
$$
\begin{aligned}e^ze^{1/z}&=\Big(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}\Big)\Big(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{m!z^m}\Big)\\&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\Big(\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{(m+n)!m!}\Big)z^n,\end{aligned}
$$
where $1/k!=0$ for $k<0$.

Now, I'm not sure how to compute the annulus of convergence... any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is $0<|z|<\infty$.

Comment: First can you determine for which $z$ the series converges absolutely?

Comment: Notice that the power series for $e^z$ converges (uniformly) everywhere, so this is equivalent to finding where $e^{1/z}$ converges. But this is clearly just all $z$ with $\vert z \vert > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the term in the product that is a constant times $z^6$ should be
$$
\frac 1 {6!0!} z^6\cdot z^0 + \frac 1 {7!1!} z^7\cdot z^{-1} + \frac 1 {8!2!} z^8\cdot z^{-2} + \frac 1{9!3!} z^9\cdot z^{-3} + \cdots
$$
And the term that is a constant times $z^{-6}$ is the same except that, for example, instead of $\dfrac 1 {9!3!} z^9\cdot z^{-3}$ one has $\dfrac 1 {9!3!} z^{-9}\cdot z^3.$ Thus both of those terms have the same coefficient.

So that coefficient is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1 {(|n|+k)!k!}
$$
So we can write
$$
e^{z + 1/z} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1 {(n+k)!k!} \left( z^n + \frac 1 {z^n} \right).
$$